# Determining if Galois group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I found a short problem while reviewing some material.

True/False: The splitting field over $\mathbb Q$ of the polynomial $x^{17} − 5 \in  \mathbb Q[x]$ has a cyclic Galois group.

It's clear that this splitting field is a Galois extension, but I'm not sure how to solve the problem. Any help would be great.

Comment: The extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[17]{5})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not Galois, so the Galois group of the splitting field of the polynomial cannot be abelian, thus cannot be cyclic.

Comment: @Crostul The product is semidirect.

Comment: @Lukas Why is that not Galois?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[17]{5})$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}$, but $x^{17}-5$ clearly has complex roots, hence it cannot contain all of them.